# Encrypt in Java and decrypt in PHP using AES-128-ECB method

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I'm fairly new to JS and PHP, sorry if what I'm asking is too basic.

I am trying to send encrypted data via POST method within a form. I need to encrypt the data in JS as it changes dynamically when the user wants it. Then I'll use openssl_decrypt after using POST. I tried but was unsuccessful. I'm doing something wrong (I really don't know what I'm doing ...) because the JS and PHP results don't match. Summing up, this is what I want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!-- Here I use the crypto package -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>
<!-- Here I use the crypto package -->

<?php
define("stringToEncode", "2");
define("KEY", "123456789");
define("COD", "AES-128-ECB");

echo "Encryption result with PHP: ".openssl_encrypt("2", COD, KEY);
?> 
<div>Encryption result with JS: <label id='demo'></label>.</div>

<script>
encryptedAES=CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(<?php echo '"'.stringToEncode.'"' ?>,<?php echo '"'.KEY.'"' ?>);
plainText=encryptedAES.toString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=plainText;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone comes up with something?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Taking the script from this question [CryptoJS AES-128-ECB and PHP openssl_encrypt don't match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894466/cryptojs-aes-128-ecb-and-php-openssl-encrypt-dont-match) I also got the exactly same result of the encryption for PHP and JS. The interesting point is that it only works when the KEY has 16 alpha, numeric or alphanumeric string (without special characters like ñ or ç). I already warned that I am not an expert so I have no idea what is happening. If someone wants to find an explanation, I leave here a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!-- Here I use the crypto package -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>
<!-- Here I use the crypto package -->

<?php
define("stringToEncode", "2");
define("COD", "AES-128-ECB");
define("KEY", "429885118246456Y");


echo "Encryption result with PHP: ".openssl_encrypt(stringToEncode, COD, KEY);
?> 

<div>Encryption result with JS: <label id="demo"></label>.</div>
<script>
const key = <?php echo "'".KEY."'" ?>;
let k = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
encryptedAES = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(<?php echo "'".stringToEncode."'" ?>, k, {mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB});
plainText=encryptedAES.toString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=plainText;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to encrypt the data on the client-side to decrypt it on the server? That's what TLS (HTTPS) is for. What are you worried about?

Comment: what I want to do is that when I send data to a session variable using a POST nobody can access or change them (or if they are changed prevent a certain action from being executed). For this I need to encrypt them following the same method in JS and PHP.

Comment: Nobody can access or change them where? While the data is going through the Internet? Again, that's what TLS is for. Also, just because you encrypt it, doesn't mean you will be able to detect changes in the data. You need *authenticated* encryption.

Comment: _...it only works when the KEY has 16 alpha... (without special characters like ñ or ç)... I have no idea what is happening:_ If you use an invalid key (not equal to 16, 24 or 32 bytes) CryptoJS uses parameters outside the AES definition due to a **bug** and produces an AES incompatible result. PHP, in contrast, cuts off such keys, or expands them with 0 values until the specified size (e.g. 16 bytes for AES-128-ECB) is reached. _Therefore, if the key is invalid, no matching result can be expected._ By the way ç or ñ are UTF8-encoded with 2 bytes per char, which results here in a 17 bytes key.

Comment: Hi Topaco, thank you for such a pedagogical answer. I did not know that.